# Why malloc allocated memory size is (24+16n) bytes?

Tags: malloc

I am wondering why malloc always allocates a memory zone of size 24+16n bytes?

In the following code whatever BUFSIZE is, the allocated size reported by malloc_usable_size equals 24 + a multiple of 16, for example: 24, 40, 56, 72...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#define BUFSIZE 20
using namespace std;

int main(int argv, char** argc)
{
    char * buf = static_cast<char *> (malloc(BUFSIZE));
    size_t bufsize = malloc_usable_size(buf);
    cout << "malloc_usable_size (buf) = " << bufsize << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply a page table entry header plus the allocation granularity of your libc/OS (which seems to be 16B).

On other systems, these numbers might be different.